# How to add XML child nodes to multiple parent nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file like this.

```
<ArrayOfALternateUnitModel>
<ALternateUnitModel>
<UnitId>1048</UnitId>
<Name> CARTON</Name>
</ALternateUnitModel>

<ALternateUnitModel>
<UnitId>2063</UnitId>
<Name> PACKET</Name>
</ALternateUnitModel>
</ArrayOfALternateUnitModel>
```

what i need is.

```
<ArrayOfALternateUnitModel>
<ALternateUnitModel>
<UnitId>1048</UnitId>
<Name> CARTON</Name>
<NewChild>new child</NewChild>
</ALternateUnitModel>

<ALternateUnitModel>
<UnitId>2063</UnitId>
<Name> PACKET</Name>
<NewChild>new child</NewChild>
</ALternateUnitModel>
</ArrayOfALternateUnitModel>
```

My code looks like this.

```
xmlDoc.Load(xmlStream);
XmlElement childElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("NewChild");
childElement.InnerText = "new child";
XmlNode parentNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("ArrayOfALternateUnitModel/ALternateUnitModel");
parentNode.AppendChild(childElement);
```

Output goes like this.

```
<ArrayOfALternateUnitModel>
<ALternateUnitModel>
<UnitId>1048</UnitId>
<Name> CARTON</Name>
<NewChild>new child</NewChild>
</ALternateUnitModel>

<ALternateUnitModel>
<UnitId>2063</UnitId>
<Name> PACKET</Name>
</ALternateUnitModel>
</ArrayOfALternateUnitModel>
```

In the second node its not adding child nodes. How to add child to all parent nodes?

Comment: you need to add the same value and the same name of tag?

Answer (score 0):

You take only one first node, so you can try to change these lines:

```
XmlNode parentNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("ArrayOfALternateUnitModel/ALternateUnitModel");
parentNode.AppendChild(childElement);
```

On

```
XmlNodeList parentNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("ArrayOfALternateUnitModel/ALternateUnitModel");
foreach (XmlNode parentNode in parentNodes)
    parentNode.AppendChild(childElement);
```

Comment: Hi sir i tried the code u mentioned and its giving a differnet set of result as below. The child is now adding to the second parent node of <ALternateUnitModel>........ As follows......

<ArrayOfALternateUnitModel>
<ALternateUnitModel>
<UnitId>2064</UnitId>
<Name> CUP</Name>
</ALternateUnitModel>

<ALternateUnitModel>
<UnitId>2063</UnitId>
<Name> PACKET</Name>
<NewChild>new child</NewChild>
</ALternateUnitModel>
</ArrayOfALternateUnitModel>

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

- You cannot append a single element to multiple parents. An element can only have one parent.
- You need to select all the target elements, not just one.

This should work:

```
xmlDoc.Load(xmlStream);
foreach (XmlNode parent in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("ArrayOfALternateUnitModel/ALternateUnitModel"))
{
    XmlElement childElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("NewChild");
    childElement.InnerText = "new child";

    parent.AppendChild(childElement);
}
```

Comment: Thabnk you sir, that worked. Now i understood what was my error. Thanks for your time.